# My player is going through walls(Even tho they are rigid bodies) and the script below doesn't work(C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Ok, so i wanna make a flappy birds-like game and i'm a noob, i have almost no experience in unity and i started learning c# and programming at all 1 week ago....
so don't expect much from me pls
So, my rigid body is going through walls even tho i have the component rigid body 2D on my walls
And i wanna make a script that changes your scene to main menu if you collide with a wall and it looks like this:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 public class SceneSwitch : MonoBehaviour {  
   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
     SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

 }


    i don't have any error but it just doesn't work.
```

(Srry about the spacing, i'm new to the platform and i don't really know how to use it)

Comment: Make sure both the bird, and the walls, have colliders. Also make sure none has "is trigger" ticked. Does that solve it? Good luck in your programming endeavours!

Comment: Hi, yes, i made sure that both sprites have colliders, and i also have my player tagged player and all, but after i read your comment i tried unchecking "Is trigger" and now my player doesn't go through walls anymore, does that have anything to do with the script or something ?

Comment: Triggers are for non-collidable rigidbodies where you still want to check the collisions, though. Now that you unchecked it, you solved the problem. Note you now want to use `OnCollisionEnter` in your code instead of `OnTriggerEnter`. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, i've done some research, changed the script OnCollisionEnter, like you've said and it now works.TYSM!

Comment: Is this really Visual-Studio specific? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using a

> rigid body 2D

Make sure all your colliders are `XYCollider`**`2D`** and then you would also rather want to use the **2**D version [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)!

```
public class SceneSwitch : MonoBehaviour 
{  
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

In Unity the 3D and 2D Physics are completely separated engines and do not interact in any way. So the Physics2D know nothing about the 3D message `OnTriggerEnter` but only the 2D message `OnTriggerEnter2D`.